# jQuery serialize / serializeArray from an element that is not a form

Tags: jquery

I haven't found a concrete answer as to whether this is possible, but it seems like it should be...

I would like to serialize all the input elements contained in a div. I can't use a form, because it would be nested within another form. I would then get the values and post them via ajax.

Here is the jsFiddle example I am playing with:

http://jsfiddle.net/9uyz5/

If I change the root  to a  it works as expected.

Thanks for your help.

I've modified the jsfiddle from this other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/25020

Comment: I've written a blog response to your question.
Here's how to serialize dom elements. I've also covered the possibility of creating a JSON string to be inserted in the database: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-serialize-elements-outside-forms.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery to serialize only elements within a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

you need to serialize all the inputs inside your container, not the actual container itself.  so:

```
$('div :input').serialize()
```

Comment: out of curiosity, I find this is somewhat unexpected, why does $('#myForm').serialize() work?

Comment: A bit late I know but, `$('#myForm').serialize()` works because it is designed to serialize all elements in a form **or** a jQuery array of input elements. [As stated in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 10):

Try this, to get all.

```
$('#divID *').serialize()
```

Answer (score 7):

this also works with

```
$('div :input').serializeArray()
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

For serializing the contents of the div with a button, this will be the more efficient way as it doesn't traverse through the entire dom.

`$(this).closest('div').find("input,select,textarea").serialize();`

make sure to attach this with the button event and make sure to include [event.preventdefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) with the button so that it does not submit the primary form if the div is inside it.