# serializeArray() without a <form>?

Tags: jquery

How do I `serializeArray()` the `input` and `textarea` inside the `.panel` without having a `form`?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sec-form-btn", function(e) {
  var element = $(this);
  var formData = element.parents('.panel :input').serializeArray();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="h4">Day - 1</span> |
    <span class="secTitle"><input name="sec[title]" value="Day 1" type="text"></span>
    <span class="pull-right panel-menu" data-secid="11">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm sec-form-btn">Save changes</a>
      <span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw edit-sec-loader hidden"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="secDes mb10">
      <textarea name="sec[des]" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't. `serializeArray()` can only be called on a `form`. If you don't want to use a `form` element you'll need to write the logic to create the array/objects yourself

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan. what about this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589126/jquery-serialize-serializearray-from-an-element-that-is-not-a-form ?
I see that there is a solution....

Comment: Well, that uses `serialize()` which returns a querystring not an array, and the answers suggesting `$('div :input').serializeArray()` are now incorrect as it doesn't work - as you can see from this: http://jsfiddle.net/9uyz5/149/